# How to target privious element's previous element in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-html

Hey am new to javascript but putting my all efforts I have written a javascript. It was working correctly, but as I put a `<div class="flex"></div>` it stopped working. Because the button tag was targeting previous element.
My HTML

```
  <div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
   <div class="allStatus">
    <div class="block">
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p>Life is good when you have books</p>
      <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p>Google is a open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
      <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <div class="block">
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p>Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
     </div>
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p>Ferrets are better than rats</p>
      <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

My javascript

```
buttons.forEach((copystatus) => {
  copystatus.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const copylatest = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    const copyText = document.createElement('textarea');
    copyText.value = copylatest;
    document.body.appendChild(copyText);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(copyText);
    copyalert.style.visibility="visible"
    e.target.parentElement.appendChild(copyalert);
    setTimeout(function() {copyalert.style.visibility ="hidden"},700);
    
  })
})
```

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make two variables, one is the element's previous element and the other is the previous element's previous element

```
var x = document.getElementById("item2").previousSibling;
var y= x.previousSibling;
```

Comment: var x = document.getElementById("item2").previousSibling;
var y= x.previousSibling;

Answer (score 0):

You can just chain the `previousElementSibling` property because that will return you a HTMLElement. However it would be better to target the desired element by another selector (class forexample) so your code won't break the next time you add an element to the html.

```js
document.querySelector('Button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.innerText);
});
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: Pls use my constant and veriable and target <p> from the button below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to copy the text within `div.latestates > p`, you can query for `p` within `Element.closest`:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", bttnClick);

function bttnClick(evt) {
  console.clear();
  console.log(evt.target.closest(".latestatus").querySelector("p").innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="mainStatus">
  <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
  <div class="allStatus">
    <div class="block">
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p>Life is good when you have books</p>
        <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p>Google is a open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
        <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p>Cats are better than dogs.</p>
        <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p>Ferrets are better than rats</p>
        <div class="flex"><button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button> <span class="randomStatusCopyAlert">Copied!</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```